# Using millis() and micros() inside an interrupt routine

Tags: interrupt, timers, millis

The documentation for [`attachInterrupt()`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/AttachInterrupt) says:

> ... `millis()` relies on interrupts to count, so it will never increment inside an ISR. Since `delay()` requires interrupts to work, it will not work if called inside an ISR. `micros()` works initially, but will start behaving erratically after 1-2 ms. ...

How does `micros()` differ from `millis()` (except of course for their precision)? Does the above warning mean that using `micros()` inside an interrupt routine is always a bad idea?

Context - I want to [measure low pulse occupancy](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/22120/19445), so I need to trigger my routine when my input signal changes and record the current time.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The other answers are very good, but I want to elaborate on how `micros()` works. It *always* reads the current hardware timer (possibly `TCNT0`) which is constantly being updated by the hardware (in fact, every 4 µs because of the prescaler of 64). It then adds in the Timer 0 overflow count, which is updated by a timer overflow interrupt (multiplied by 256).

Thus, even inside an ISR, you can rely on `micros()` updating. However *if you wait too long* then you miss the overflow update, and then the result returned will go down (i.e you will get 253, 254, 255, 0, 1, 2, 3 etc.)

This is `micros()` - slightly simplified to remove defines for other processors:

```C++
unsigned long micros() {
    unsigned long m;
    uint8_t oldSREG = SREG, t;
    cli();
    m = timer0_overflow_count;
    t = TCNT0;
    if ((TIFR0 & _BV(TOV0)) && (t < 255))
        m++;
    SREG = oldSREG;
    return ((m << 8) + t) * (64 / clockCyclesPerMicrosecond());
}
```

The code above allows for the overflow (it checks the TOV0 bit) so it can cope with the overflow while interrupts are off but only **once** - there is no provision for handling two overflows.

---

**TLDR;**

- Don't do delays inside an ISR
- If you must do them, you can time then with `micros()` but not `millis()`. Also `delayMicroseconds()` is a possibility.
- Don't delay more than 500 µs or so, or you'll miss a timer overflow.
- Even short delays may cause you to you miss incoming serial data (at 115200 baud you will get a new character every 87 µs).

Comment: Not able to understand the statement given below that is used in micros(). Could you please elaborate? Since ISR is written, TOV0 flag will be cleared as soon as ISR is entered and hence below condition may not become true!. if ((TIFR0 & _BV(TOV0)) && (t < 255)) m++;

Comment: `micros()` isn't an ISR. It is a normal function. The TOV0 flag lets you test the hardware to see if the timer overflow has happened (but not been processed yet).

Comment: Since the test is done with interrupts off you know the flag will not change during the test.

Comment: So you mean to say after cli() inside micros() function, if any overflow occurs, that needs to be checked? That make sense. Otherwise even though micros is not a function, TIMER0_OVF_vect ISR will clear TOV0 in TIFR0 is what my doubt was.

Comment: Also why TCNT0 is compared against 255 to see if it is less than 255? After cli() if TCNT0 reach 255 what will happen?

Comment: Even with interrupts off the hardware timers will continue to count. I think the test for < 255 is because of a possible situation where the overflow flag has been set but the timer is still at 255 (so it hasn't quite overflowed yet). The next one up from 255 would be 0.

Comment: *TIMER0_OVF_vect ISR will clear TOV0 in TIFR0 is what my doubt was* - the timer might have overflowed and the ISR has been scheduled but not yet run.

Comment: In particular after the line `t = TCNT0;` the timer might overflow *just now* so we need to test the overflow flag, and it `t` is less than 255, and the overflow flag is set, then it probably overflowed between those two instructions.

Answer (score 9):

It is not *wrong* to use `millis()` or `micros()` within an interrupt routine.

It *is* wrong to use them incorrectly.

The main thing here is that while you are in an interrupt routine "the clock isn't ticking".  `millis()` and `micros()` won't change (well, `micros()` will initially, but once it goes past that magic millisecond point where a millisecond tick is required it all falls apart.)

So you can certainly call on `millis()` or `micros()` to find out the current time within your ISR, but don't expect that time to change.

It is that lack of change in the time that is being warned about in the quote you provide.  `delay()` relies on `millis()` changing to know how much time has passed. Since it doesn't change `delay()` can never finish.

So essentially `millis()` and `micros()` will tell you the time *when your ISR was called* no matter when in your ISR you use them.

Comment: No, `micros()` updates. It always reads the hardware timer register.

Answer (score 6):

The quoted phrase is *not* a warning, it is merely a statement about how things work.

There's nothing intrinsically wrong with using `millis()` or `micros()` within a properly-written interrupt routine.

On the other hand, doing anything at all within an improperly-written interrupt routine is by definition wrong.

An interrupt routine that takes more than a few microseconds to do its job is, in all likelihood, improperly written.

In short:  A properly-written interrupt routine will not cause or encounter issues with `millis()` or `micros()`.

*Edit:*  Regarding “why micros() "starts behaving erratically"”, as explained in an “[examination of the Arduino micros function](https://ucexperiment.wordpress.com/2012/03/17/examination-of-the-arduino-micros-function/) ” webpage,  `micros()` code on an ordinary Uno is functionally equivalent to

```
unsigned long micros() {
  return((timer0_overflow_count << 8) + TCNT0)*(64/16);
}
```

This returns a four-byte unsigned long comprised of the three lowest bytes from `timer0_overflow_count` and one byte from the timer-0 count register.

The `timer0_overflow_count` is incremented about once per millisecond by the `TIMER0_OVF_vect` interrupt handler, as explained in an [examination of the arduino millis function](https://ucexperiment.wordpress.com/2012/03/16/examination-of-the-arduino-millis-function/)  webpage.

Before an interrupt handler begins, AVR hardware disables interrupts.  If (for example) an interrupt handler were to run for five milliseconds with interrupts still disabled, at least four timer 0 overflows would be missed.  [Interrupts written in C code in the Arduino system are not reentrant (capable of correctly handling multiple overlapping executions within the same handler) but one could write a reentrant assembly language handler that reenables interrupts before it begins a time-consuming process.]

In other words, timer overflows don't “stack up”; whenever an overflow occurs before the interrupt from the previous overflow has been handled, the `millis()` counter loses a millisecond, and the discrepancy in `timer0_overflow_count` in turn makes `micros()` wrong by a millisecond too.

Regarding “shorter than 500 μs” as an upper time limit for interrupt processing,  “to prevent blocking the timer interrupt for too long”, you could go up to just under 1024 μs (eg 1020 μs) and `millis()` still would work, most of the time.  However, I regard an interrupt handler that takes more than 5 μs as a sluggard, more than 10 μs as slothful, more than 20 μs as snail-like.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on "how things work", in particular why `micros()` "start behaving erratically"? And what do you mean by "properly-written interrupt routine"? I assume it means "shorter than 500us" (to prevent blocking the timer interrupt for too long), "using volatile variables for communication" and "not calling library code" as much as possible, is there anything else?

Comment: @PetrPudlák, see edit

Answer (score 0):

You should never do anything inside an ISR except set a flag saying you got the interrupt, and return.

Comment: While it is true that one should keep ISR code as short as possible, this statement is excessive. There are many situations where doing something else is relevant. In fact, just setting a flag is useless: the hardware, at least on AVR, does that for you, without having to enable the interrupt.

Comment: @EdgarBonet, I am not sure, but I think high rep users can vote to delete an answer with negative score

Comment: @Juraj: Indeed, you are right.

Comment: It is different than the advice you've gotten maybe, but it simplifies code and encourages good program structure.  Open your mind and see how the suggestion would make the problems in the sample code go away.  The only thing "excessive" is my 30 years of coding firmware for IBM :)